# Show that $Z(θ^G)≤H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, characters

Suppose $H ≤ G$ and $θ \in Char(H)$. Show that $Z(θ^G)≤H$.  ($Z$ is the centre and $θ^G$ is the character induced by $G$)

Comment: What do you mean by the characteristic of $H$?

Comment: $\sigma(\theta) =\theta, \forall \sigma \in \text{Aut}(H)$

Comment: What is $\theta^G$?

Comment: So you did not actually mean the characteristic of $H$, but the set of characters of $H$?

Comment: Hmm, probably a calculation like the one showing that this holds for the kernel also works for the center.

Comment: Hint: If $\sigma(\theta) = \theta, \forall \sigma \in \textrm{Aut}(H)$ then $\sigma_g \cdot H = gHg^{-1}=H$.

Comment: @Rod That seems completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: I think I am confusing what $\theta^G$ actually is. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Rod As already added, $\theta$ is a character of $H$ and $\theta^G$ is the induced character.

Comment: Okay, well yes then this is completely unrelated from what I just read about characters, sorry.

Comment: But what does $Z(\theta^G)$ mean? What is the centre of a character?

Comment: If $\theta \in Char(G)$, then $Z(\theta)=\{g \in G : |\theta(g)|=\theta(1)\}$

Comment: Well if $g \not\in H$, then $\theta^G((g)$ is the sub of fewer than $|G|/|H|$ character values of $\theta$, so its absolute value is kless than $\theta^G(1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $K \leq G$, we write $core_G(K)$ for the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $K$. It is easily seen that $core_G(K)=\bigcap_{x \in G}K^x$, the intersection of all the $G$-conjugates of $K$.

**Proposition** Let $\theta$ be a character of $H \leq G$. Then
$$Z(\theta^G)=core_G(Z(\theta)).$$
**Proof** Let $\chi=\theta^G$, then $g \in Z(\chi)$ if and only if 
$$\frac{1}{\#H}|\sum_{x \in G}\theta^{o}(x^{-1}gx)|=[G:H]\theta(1)$$ $\iff$ 
$$|\sum_{x \in G}\theta^{o}(x^{-1}gx)|=\sum_{x \in G}\theta(1).$$
Since $|\theta^{o}(x^{-1}gx)| \leq \theta(1)$ and using the triangle inequality, we see that  $g \in Z(\chi)$ if and only if $|\theta^{o}(x^{-1}gx)| = \theta(1)$ for all $x \in G$. But this is the case exactly when $g \in Z(\theta)^x$ for all $x \in G$.$\square$

Note that it now follows that $Z(\theta^G) \leq H.$ In addition: in a similar manner, $ker(\theta^G)=core_G(ker(\theta))$.

Answer (score 0):

Well if $g \not\in H$, then $\theta^G(g)$ is the sum of fewer than $|G|/|H|$ character values of $\theta$, so its absolute value is less than $\theta^G(1)$.